# How to generate entities to database

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, oop

I create a linq to sql class 
Create all entities that i need for my app

Now i need to create this entities in the database
is there a way to generate all of my entities?

yes i want to generate tables for the entities

Comment: Do you mean that you need to add entities, or that you need to create the database schema?

Comment: It sounds like he wants LINQ to create the tables, and I don't believe it can do that, as I tend to need the tables to create the context classes in the first place.

Comment: Yes i want the Tables to be generated, or some database SQL script so that i could run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way out of these problem. after the diagram is created in the linq2sql file, you just have to invoke the CreateDatabase method of your datacontext. 
Here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399420.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if you have it installed (and what version) Visio can do this for you (you must have the Entrprise Architect version from 2003+).

If you are trying to do it automatically from code I am not aware of a way to do this (at least not just with .NET). Some OR/M frameworks provide this functionality but the do it by building static scripts at compile time.